# How to load overrides from external file in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a php function that applies a number of set transformations to the input it receives, and then returns it as output. Say it generates a url for input keywords.

Now, for some keywords I'd like to override the default output returned by the function and use another specifically provided for that keyword.

I could of course hard-code the exception keywords in the function itself, but I wondered if there is a cleaner way to do this (a sort of design pattern/template in PHP).

Can you propose a php solution for this:
1. There is an "overrides" configuration file, say CSV or JSON, accessible to the php application that lists pairs of .

2. Given an input, the function first checks if it matches any keyword in the overrides file.
3. If a match is found, the function will output the specialURL. Otherwise, if no match is found in the file, it will perform its default operations.

How to do with cleanly, and efficiently, given that the overrides are rare?

Comment: Store it in a config file, or a database. As far as config files go, try INI, JSON, YAML, and if none of those work, then something increasigly ugly like CSV or XML.

Comment: There is nothing built-in to PHP, but if you search you can find many ways to build an array / map of (x > override to y) from a file.  As written this is too broad for a SO-style answer.  Pick one method and let us know if you get stuck?